# How to make a two-dimensional matrix w/o for?

Tags: matlab, matrix, simplify

I'm coding the matrix for the 2-dimensional graph, now.
Although it's so simple equation, it takes a lot of time for performing. I think it could get faster.
especially, "for - command term" could be simplified I think.
How can I simplify this?

```
q=1:1:30
x(q)=330+q*0.3
F=1:30:8970
T=x(1)-0.3:0.001:x(30)+0.3
n=size(T,2)
k=1:1:n
for a=1:1:30
I(a,k)=F(a)*exp(-2.*(T(:,k)))
end
happy=sum(I)
plot(k,I)
```

---

Comment: This code should not take long, nor should the for loop make it much faster. The only thing that takes long is the printing on the screen (because you have not added `;`). This code (without the plot) runs on 10 miliseconds on my PC (but 4.7seconds if you print all to screen). You want FASTER than that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the time is used to print results. Try to use `;` at the end of each line, it will fasten computation.

You can also replace the for loop by the following element by element computation:

```
a = (1:1:30).';
aux = repmat(exp(-2.*(T(:,k))), length(a), 1);
a = repmat(a, 1, length(k));
I = a.'.*aux.';
```

Comment: Note that this is only marginally faster than preallocating `I` and running the loop. But Upvoted because its indeed a marginally faster solution. I would still use the for loop for clarity though.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, I agree with you. Adding ; will be fast enough.

Comment: I never considered printing time. after adding ; It got faster! And i will also refer to your code. Thanks both of @PedroRodriguez and AnderBogior for teaching me.